# How to disable HTTP_PROXY in Minikube?

Tags: minikube

I'm testing an installation of a chart in air-gap environment using Minikube. Apparently, my own machine has its HTTP_PROXY set. This impacts /etc/systemd/system.conf.d/proxy-default-environment.conf to contain the same HTTP_PROXY plus control-plane.minikube.internal.

The first time I start `minikube start` I manually run `export` for all *_PROXY including *_proxy to enable minikube initialization. Then, on the second round, I manually export them all with empty value. Still, the Minikube has access to the proxy and I can still download images from docker repos.

It looks to me as if it will lookup the default proxy settings if not defined within environment variable during `minikube start`

How to completely disable HTTP_PROXY in Minikube without I have to change my machine's /etc/environment?

Answer (score 1):

The content of  /etc/systemd/system.conf.d/proxy-default-environment.conf comes from $HOME/.docker/config.json. It's preferable to set it /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf